# Using .split to process user input

Tags: java

I am creating a text-adventure game in Java in which the user enters commands such as 'H' for help or 'N' to move North. In certain cases, the user will need to enter something such as 'T key' to take a key that is in that room. So because of this I need to use the split method to split the command and the item that the user wants to take. I'm getting really stuck in the return part as in some cases the string returned will only be the command if they enter one letter and in other cases it will be both the command and item. All help is appreciated!

This is my code in the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GameEngine {
    private Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Player player1 = new Player("playerName", 0);
    private int currentLocation = player1.currentRoom;
    private boolean stillPlaying = true; //When this is true, the game continues to run

    private Item[] items = {
            new Item ("map","a layout of your house", 10 ),
            //new Item ("battery", "a double A battery", 5),
            new Item ("battery", "a double A battery", 5),
            new Item ("flashlight", "a small silver flashlight", 10),
            new Item ("key", "this unlocks some door in your house", 15),
    };

    //Locations {roomName, description, item}
    private Locale[] locales = {
            new Locale("bedroom","You see the outline of a bed with your childhood stuffed bear on it.",items[0]),
            new Locale("hallway","A carpeted floor and long pictured walls lie ahead of you.",null),
            new Locale("kitchen","The shining surface of your stove reflects the pale moonlight coming in the window over the sink.",items[1]),
            new Locale("bathroom","You find yourself standing in front of a mirror, looking back at yourself.",items[2]),
            new Locale("living room","You stub your toe on the sofa in the room, almost falling right into the TV.",null),
            new Locale("dining room","You bump the china cabinet which holds your expensive dishes and silverware.",items[3]),
            new Locale("office","The blinking light from the monitor on your desk can be seen in the dark",null),
            new Locale("library","The smell of old books surrounds you.",null),
            new Locale("basement","You reach the top of some stairs and upon descending down, you find the large metal generator.",null),
    };

    //Matrix for rooms
    private int[][] roomMap = {
            //   N,E,S,W
            {6,1,-1,-1}, //Bedroom (room 0)
            {4,2,3,0}, //Hallway (room 1)
            {-1,-1,5,1}, //Kitchen (room 2)
            {1,-1,-1,-1}, //Bathroom (room 3)
            {-1,7,1,-1}, //Living Room (room 4)
            {2,-1,-1,-1}, //Dining Room (room 5)
            {-1,-1,0,-1}, //Office (room 6)
            {8,-1,-1,4}, //Library (room 7)
            {-1,-1,7,-1} //Basement (room 8)
    };

    private BreadcrumbTrail trail = new BreadcrumbTrail();

    //Move method
    private String[] dirNames = {"North", "East", "South", "West"};

    //Welcome Message
    public void displayIntro(){
        System.out.println("\tWelcome to Power Outage!");
        System.out.println("=================================================");
        System.out.print("\tLet's start by creating your character.\n\n\tWhat is your name? ");

        //Will read what name is entered and return it
        player1.playerName = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\n\tHello, " +player1.playerName+ ". Let's start the game! \n\n\tPress any key to begin.");
        System.out.print("=================================================");

        //Will move to next line when key is pressed
        userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\tYou wake up in your bedroom. \n\n\tThe power has gone out and it is completely dark.");
        System.out.println("\n\tYou must find your way to the basement to start the generator.");
    }

    private void displayMoveInfo(){
        System.out.println("\n\tMove in any direction by typing, 'N', 'S', 'E', or 'W'.");
        System.out.println("\n\tTake an item from a room by pressing 'T'.");
        System.out.println("\n\tTo go back to the room you were just in type 'B'.");
        System.out.println("\n\tType 'H' at any time for help and 'Q' to quit the game. Good luck!");
        System.out.println("\n\tPress any key.");
    }
    private void move(int dir) {
        int dest = roomMap[currentLocation][dir];
        if (dest >= 0 && dest != 8) {
            System.out.println("=================================================");
            System.out.println("\tYou have moved " + dirNames[dir]);
            currentLocation = dest;
            System.out.println("\n\tYou are in the "+locales[currentLocation].roomName+".");
            System.out.println("\n\t"+locales[currentLocation].description);
            Locale locale = locales[currentLocation];
            itemPresent();
            //Drop breadcrumb at current location
            trail.dropCrumb(currentLocation);
        }
        //If the player reaches the basement and wins
        else if (dest == 8){
            System.out.println("\tCongratulations!! You have found the basement and turned on the generator! \n\n\tYou have won the game!");
            System.out.println("\n\tTHANKS FOR PLAYING!!!!!!");
            System.out.println("\n\tCopyright 2016 \n\n");
            stillPlaying = false;
        }
        //If dest == -1
        else {
            System.out.println("\tThere is no exit that way, please try again.");
        }
    }//End of Move

    private void itemPresent(){
        Locale locale = locales[currentLocation];
        if(locale.item != null){
            System.out.println("\n\tThere is a " + locale.item + " in this room.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\n\tThere is no item in this room.");
        }
    }

    public Command getCommandFromResponse(String response) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        String[] split = response.split(" ");

        if(split.length < 1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid command.");
        }

        Command command = new Command(split[0]);
        if(split.length >= 2) {
            command.setItem(split[1]);
        }

        return command;
    }

    //All possible responses to keys pressed
    public void processInput(){
        displayMoveInfo();
        Command userCommand = getCommandFromResponse(userInput.nextLine());

        while(stillPlaying){
            if(player1.currentRoom != 8 && !"Q".equalsIgnoreCase(userCommand.getCommand()) ){

                //Map
                if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("M")){
                    //only print if the player has the map
                    //String[] inventory = player1.inventory;
                    int mapFoundAt = -1;
                    if(player1.inventory != null){
                        for(int i=0; i < player1.inventory.size(); i++){
                            Item checkItem;
                            checkItem = player1.inventory.get(i);
                            if(checkItem.itemName.equals("map")){
                                mapFoundAt = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(mapFoundAt >=0 ){
                            System.out.println("Here is your map: \n\n\t\t\tbasement\n\noffice\t  living room\tlibrary\n\nbedroom\t   hallway\tkitchen\n\n\t   bathroom \tdining room");
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("\tYou do not have the map in your inventory.");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("\tYou don't have any items in your inventory.");
                    }
                    break;
                }//End of Map


                //Take
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("T")){
                    Locale locale = locales[currentLocation];
                    if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("T")){

                    }
                    if(locale.item != null){
                        //-User must enter item name with the command
                        System.out.println("Enter the command and item you would like to take.");
                        userCommand = getCommandFromResponse(userInput.nextLine());

                        if(userCommand.command.equals(locale.item.itemName)){
                            //-add the item to the player's inventory
                            player1.inventory.add(locale.item);
                            System.out.println("\tA " + locale.item + " was added to your inventory");
                            if(locale.item.itemName.equals("map")){
                                System.out.println("\n\tTo view the map press 'M'.");
                            }
                            //-remove the item from the current location
                            locale.item = null;
                            System.out.println("\n\tYou can view your inventory by pressing 'I' or drop an item by pressing 'D'.");
                            //-Add the item's worth to the score and set the items worth to zero to prevent double scoring
                            player1.score += locale.item.value;
                            System.out.println(locale.item.value + " points have been added to your score.");
                            System.out.println("\n\tThis is your current score: "+player1.score);
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("That item is not at this location.");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("There is no item to pick up here");
                    }

                }//End of Take

                //Help
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
                    displayMoveInfo();
                    break;
                }

                //Inventory
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("I")){
                    if(player1.inventory != null){
                        System.out.println("\tThese are the items in your inventory: "+player1.inventory+".");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("\tYou currently have no items in your inventory.");
                        System.out.println("\tTo pick up an item in a room, press 'T'.");
                    }
                    break;
                }

                //Drop
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
                    //Show the list of items in the player's inventory with numbers associated with them
                    if(player1.inventory.size() != 0){
                        System.out.println("\tThese are the items available to drop: " +player1.inventory);
                    }
                    else if(player1.inventory.size() == 0){
                        System.out.println("\tYou have no items in your inventory to drop.");
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("\tEnter the name of the item you would like to drop.");
                    String itemToDrop = userInput.nextLine();
                    Locale locale = locales[currentLocation];
                    if(locale.item == null){
                        for(int i=0; i < player1.inventory.size(); i++){
                            Item checkItem;
                            checkItem = player1.inventory.get(i);
                            if(checkItem.itemName.equalsIgnoreCase(itemToDrop)){
                                //Remove item entered from a player's inventory
                                System.out.println("\tYou have dropped the " +checkItem.itemName+ ".");
                                player1.inventory.remove(i);
                                //Place the item at the player's current location so it can be picked up again
                                locale.item = checkItem;
                                //Subtract five points from the player's score
                                player1.score -= 5;
                                System.out.println("\tFive points have been subtracted from your score.");
                                System.out.println("\n\tThis is your current score: "+player1.score);

                            }
                            else if(i==player1.inventory.size() && checkItem.itemName != itemToDrop){
                                System.out.println("\tThat is not an item in your inventory.");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("\tThere is already an item at this location, you can't drop an item.");
                    }
                    break;
                }//End of Drop


                //Backtrack
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
                    //Pick up breadcrumb
                    trail.pickupCrumb();
                    if(trail.hasMoreCrumbs() == false){
                        //Move to previous crumb
                        currentLocation = trail.currentCrumb();
                        System.out.println("\n\tYou are in the "+locales[currentLocation].roomName+".");
                        System.out.println("\n\t"+locales[currentLocation].description);
                        itemPresent();
                    }
                    //When the trail is empty, drop the last breadcrumb, don't move the player again
                    else{
                        trail.dropCrumb(currentLocation);
                        System.out.println("\tYou are at the beginning of your breadcrumb trail, you can't backtrack any more.");
                    }
                    break;
                }//End of Backtrack


                //North
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
                    move(0);
                    break;
                }

                //East
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
                    move(1);
                    break;
                }

                //South
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
                    move(2);
                    break;
                }

                //West
                else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("W")){
                    move(3);
                    break;
                }

                //If any key is pressed other than those above
                else{
                    System.out.println("\tInvalid command!");
                    break;
                }
            }//End of Quit if statement

            else if(userCommand.command.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!\n\n");
                stillPlaying = false;
            }
        }//End of while
    }//End of pressedKey method

    public void play(){
        displayIntro();
        System.out.println("=================================================");
        System.out.println("\tYou are in the bedroom.");
        Locale locale = locales[currentLocation];
        itemPresent();
        trail.dropCrumb(currentLocation);

        //This makes the game continue to loop
        while(stillPlaying){
            System.out.println("=================================================");
            System.out.println("\tMove in any direction.");
            processInput();

        } //End of while

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameEngine game = new GameEngine();
        game.play();
    } //End of main
} //End of class
```

This is my Player Class:
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Player {

    //Player class must have name, location, inventory, and score
    public String playerName;
    public ArrayList<Item> inventory; 
    public int score;
    public int currentRoom;

    public Player(String playerName, int currentRoom){
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.inventory = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.score = 0;
        this.currentRoom = currentRoom;
    }
}
```

This is the Command class:

```
    class Command{
        String command;
        String item;

        public Command(String comm){
            command = comm;
        }

        public Command(String comm, String item){
            this.command = comm;
            this.item = item;
        }

        public void setCommand(String command){
            this.command = command;
        }

        public void setItem(String item){
            this.item = item;
        }

        public String getCommand(){
            return this.command;
        }

        public String getItem(){
            return this.item;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return this.command + ":" + this.item;
        }
    }
```

This is my Locale class:

```
public class Locale {

    //Locale must have name, description, and Item
    public static int roomNumber;
    public String roomName;
    public String description;
    public Item item;


    public Locale(String roomName, String description, Item item){
        this.roomName = roomName;
        this.description = description;
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

This is my Item class:

```
public class Item {
    //item must have a name and a description (both strings)
    public String itemName;
    public String itemDes;
    public boolean isDiscovered;
    public int value;

    public Item (String itemName, String itemDes, int value){
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemDes = itemDes;
        this.isDiscovered = false;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return itemName + "(" + itemDes + ")";
    }
    }
```

This is my BreadcrumbTrail class:

```
public class BreadcrumbTrail {
    //dropCrumb (push)
    //pickupCrumb (pop)
    //currentCrumb (peek)
    //hasMoreCrumbs (empty)

    //Drop a new breadcrumb whenever the player arrives at a local
    class Node{
        int data;
        Node link;

        Node(int s, Node l){
            this.data = s; //element stored at the node
            this.link = l; //link to another node
        }
    }//End of Node class

    private Node currentCrumb;

    //Constructor
    public BreadcrumbTrail(){
        this.currentCrumb = null;
    }

    //pop
    public void pickupCrumb(){ 
        this.currentCrumb = this.currentCrumb.link;
    }

    //push
    public void dropCrumb(int s){
        Node newNode = new Node(s, this.currentCrumb);
        this.currentCrumb = newNode;
    }

    //top or peek
    public int currentCrumb(){
        return this.currentCrumb.data;
    }

    //isEmpty
    public boolean hasMoreCrumbs(){
        return this.currentCrumb == null;
    }
}
```

In the pressedkey method now the if else statements obviously don't work as I now need to change the part in front of .equals.

Comment: `split.length == 0` means that  `split` array has no elements, so there isn't even even element at index `[0]`.

Comment: Just post all of your code including the main method/class so we can see where your issue is.

Comment: Sorry its a lot of code

Comment: I don't see in the code where you need or allow the user to enter both a command and and item on the same line. It appears that you are usually just entering a command and if the command is 'T' for example, then you prompt for input on the item to take. Am i incorrect? If so where is it

Comment: You are correct there. Once the while loop in the main method loops through it will prompt the user to 'move in any direction' which is where they can enter any of the commands in the pressedKey method

Comment: I have edited your question to correct formatting and update to eliminate compile errors, proper usage of Command. By the way. Don't use all static methods in your main class. in the main method, create an instance of main and call non static methods on that instance. Also, usually you want all fields in a class private as well, or nothing(package access). I have updated your main class to reflect this as well. That should be enough to get you on your feet and off an running. Good luck and mark correct answer/upvote when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All previous answers are decent. However, I think you are better off validating the user input and if the user enters the incorrect number of objects, throw an exception to indicate invalid input instead of just logging it. It makes the code more manageable, reads better, and give you an opportunity to deal with invalid input properly:

```
      public Command getCommandFromResponse(String response) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        String[] split = response.split(" ");

        if(split.length < 1){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid command.");
        }
        if(split.length < 2){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must enter an item.");
        }

        return new Command(split[0], split[1]);
      }

      class Command{
        String command;
        String item;

        public Command(){
          command = null;
          item = null;
        }

        public Command(String comm, String item){
          this.command = comm;
          this.item = item;
        }

        public void setCommand(String command){
            this.command = command;
        }

        public void setItem(String item){
            this.item = item;
        }

        public String getCommand(){
            return this.command;
        }

        public String getItem(){
          return this.item;
        }

        public String toString(){
          return this.command + ":" + this.item;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much I will try this as my code does seem to be a little hard to read right now.

Comment: Now if I am trying to check if the user input is equal to just 'H' for help for example, how would I be able to do this as the Command must take in both comm and item?

Comment: Before returning a Command that has both the command and item, it is checking for both arguments. So, if only the 'H' was entered for the command, but no item entered, it will again throw an error that the item must be entered. Only after validating both exist will a Command object be created and returned. But, I will edit the answer to allow a default constructor with no args and also setter methods for both command and item, giving more flexibility of you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate all the help :)

Comment: So if I am using if else statements to check for the input for example if the command equals 'M'. Am I correct in using: if(Command.command.equalsIgnoreCase("M"){

Comment: Basically yes. But you wont call `Command.command` because `Command` is the class and you wont call a method in a static way. You will have an 'instance' of command that gets returned from the method, like: `Command userCommand = getCommandFromResponse(response);` Normally though it is a better practice to use the `Command.getCommand()` method, like: `userCommand.getCommand();` Also in case the command is null (but is shouldn't be), you can reverse it to prevent getting a NullPointerException: `if("M".equalsIgnoreCase(userCommand.getCommand())){`

Comment: I am still getting the error that I am trying to make a static reference to a nonstatic field userCommand.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this:

```
class UserInput {
    private String command;
    private String item;

    public UserInput() {
        command = "";
        item = "";
    }

    public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

And return an instance of it.

```
String response = userInput.nextLine();
String[] split = response.split(" ");

UserInput input = new UserInput();

if (split.length > 0) {
    input.setCommand(split[0]);
    if (split.length == 2) {
        input.setItem(split[1]);
    }

    return input;
}

System.out.println("Invalid command");
return null;
```

Comment: Thank you!  When I implement this, there is an error saying it can't convert from UserInput to String. Is this an easy fix?

Comment: Change your method's return type to the `UserInput`.

Comment: Sorry haha I should I realized that.

Comment: Keep in mind that, if input is invalid, method is returning `null`. So you must do a null check after you get `UserInput`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = userInput.nextLine();
    String command = null;
    String item = null;

    String[] split = response.split(" ");

    if (split.length == 1) {
        command = split[0];

    } else if (split.length == 2) {
        command = split[0];
        item = split[1];

    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid command");
    }

    System.out.println(command + "/" + item);
    userInput.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score -2):

if user input contains only command, then don't run the loop. Move your

```
  if(split.length == 0){
      String command = split[0];
      return command;
  }
```

before the loop.

```
    String response = userInput.nextLine();
          String[] split = response.split(" ");
              if(split.length == 0){
                  String command = split[0];
                  return command;
              }
          for(int i=0; i < split.length; i++){
 //use simple java class to store the result 
              if(split.length == 1){
                  String item = split[1];
                  return item;
              }
              else{
                  System.out.println("Invalid command");
              }
          }
```

Comment: This definately does not work and would still throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception when attempting to access split[0] if length = 0

Comment: Ah, my mistake to copy the OPs code. just wan to show him the idea.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even realize my mistake there.